# FFMPEG creating AC3 audio and displays a warning

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Good afternoon!

For example, there is the origin multichannel file with 5.1 channels and i am trying to create ac3 audio through ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.w64 -c:a ac3 -ac 6 -b:a 640k output.ac3
```

Command is working, but each time, when coding, a yellow warning pops up:

```
[w64 @ 00000000008e9c40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
```

Please tell me how can i clear this warning for wave 64 format (.w64) ?

To get rid of this warning, do i need to do two passes of ffmpeg, or is one enough?

Answer (score 2):

## Ignore it

Your file has no duration info so `ffmpeg` has to guess. It has no effect on the output of the duration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried your command:
[ ffmpeg -i input.w64 -f null - ]
and saw that the duration and time by 1 ms is different. 
Llogan, is it possible to correct duration via ffmpeg? I would like to get the correct W64 file in duration.

Comment: @Gold.key There is nothing to fix. The duration is a guess. It is for informational purposes only. If it is off by 1 ms it does not matter.

Comment: If we know the correct duration, after "-f null -". Is it possible to write duration manually via ffmpeg, during encoding? Perhaps this will help clear the warning. Interesting, if such a algoritm exists in ffmpeg?

Comment: @Gold.key To clear the warning mux into wav before encoding to ac3. `ffmpeg -i input.w64 -c copy temp.wav`. Now when you `ffmpeg -i temp.wav out.ac3` it will not show the warning. It's an unnecessary step but is a literal method to address the warning and answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew about this method if we transcode
source file from w64 to wav, ffmpeg will not display a warning. But my source file have a big size, more than 4 GB, and the wav format is not suitable for this task. I am looking for a way to solve this task only for the wave 64 format. I need the keep the extension w64. Is there a way out?

Comment: @Gold.key You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Ignore the waring. Ignore the guessed duration. `ffmpeg` will output a file with the correct duration regardless of what the guessed duration says.